# Cameo Systems Modeler Calendar Function

Tags: sysml

Is there a Cameo Systems Modeler Calendar Function?

My team likes planning project execution using Call Behavior Actions to decompose project activities into lower level tasks and are wondering if we can create a calendar using the model elements, so changing delivery date in one place will propagate the change everywhere.

We can't download MS Project on our company assets